# Como salir de una previsualización de una imagen sin usar el botón "x"

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, modal

Me gustaría poder salir de una previsualización de una imagen sin usar el botón "x" sinó clickando fuera de la imagen previsualizada como si de un modal se tratara

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

què tendría que añadir y quitar en su código para poder hacer click fuera de la previsualización y que al hacerlo ésta se cerrara.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un cambio sencillo. Lo que tendrias que cambiar es:

- El evento de cierre del modal iría en el div que contiene el modal.
- En la imagen dentro del modal, detener la propagación del evento (para evitar que se cierre el modal si el click es sobre la imagen):

```js
// Cerrar el modal al click
modal.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Evitar la propagación 
modalImg.onclick = function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

[Aquí tienes un fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mou59wyx/1/) que que hace lo que buscas. El cambio esta en las últimas líneas del JS